# VSTO and Office 2010

Tags: .net, vb.net, outlook, ms-office, vsto

Does VSTO 2008 work for Office 2010 or will it only be VSTO 2010? If it is VSTO 2010 then does this mean that I have to update all my clients to .NET 4.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it will work, but there may be a few settings to tinker with. Unless VSTO 2008 allows building to .NET 4.0, it will still build for 3.5.

Comment: Can confirm you would need VS 2010 IDE to build to .Net 4.0, main benefit in upgrading the solution to VSTO 2010 would be in removing the need for the custominclusionlists proj if you are in fact using that, due to lack of certificates for code signing.

Comment: @Anonymous Type: AFAIK, yes. The other major benefit for building with .NET4.0 is that you don't need to deploy PIAs.

Comment: thanks @Todd Main. I found the major pain points in upgrade to be rebuilds of custom ribbon UI classes + removing get_ prefixes (turning methods back into properties), neither of which was particularly onerous or dangerous for prod apps